# Objects shown transparent in 3d Viewport

Tags: objects, 3d-view

my object in the 3D port got Transparent even if I dont have X-Ray enabled...
In the Shading Tab everything is fine..
[image]

best regards

Comment: Looks like it could be inverted normals. Try the following : in Edit mode select All  then from the mesh menu choose Normals > Recalculate Outside.

Comment: You don't have X-Ray enabled, but as you can see in your screenshot you have _Backface Culling_ enabled in the dropdown menu you're showing us. So you have inverted normals as @3fingeredfrog already pointed out.

Comment: Now I turned off "Backface Culling". Next i choose all my object > went to edit mode > selected all faces > went to mesh > choose recalculate outside.

sadly it looks stimm the same.. As i am writing this I solved the problem myself...

You cant see it in the screenshot but for whatever reason the following proerty was wrong:
under "N" > View > Clip start >  It was set to: 0.0000001 instead of 0.1

Comment: Oh I see, yes the artifacts in the transparency should have indicated that it's an issue with the clip settings. I didn't pay attention to this detail.